# Android application unable to start in emulator with no errors in the error log

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i'm new to programming and requires some help in this issue.
I have a simple android app that is unable to start up and showed this message:"Unfortunately, the project has stopped." There are no visible errors in the project and there is no errors on the error chat log as well.

Would really appreciate some help/advice,please help me if you can
Thank You.

Comment: Try putting `Log.d("...","...")` messages in your code to determine the location of the crash.

Comment: @GaryChen Without any information how can help you?, post your code or error logcat.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse IDE? If so that might be the cause. If you are sure that your code is perfect, then try to Clean and Build the project. If it doesn't work, close the Eclipse and open it again.

Comment: Please, try to get and post some logs as Dipal Keshariya said, and provide us more information about your emulator